# Designing a class that can be tested in an if statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement, operator-overloading

I have my class, where I overloaded the `!` operator:

```
class obj
{
public:

    bool operator!() const
    { return this->str.length() == 0; }

private:

    string str;

};
```

With the `!` operator i want to check the `obj` validity, so:

```
obj o;

// if o is not a valid object
if(!o)
   cerr << "Error";
```

Now I want to have the possibility to do this:

```
// if o is a valid object
if(o)
   cout << "OK";
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using C++11, you can do this by having an `explicit operator bool`:

```
explicit operator bool() const {
    return !!*this;
}
```

This operator is called if you ever need to cast your object to a `bool` explicitly (which is done by the `if` statement automatically).  The implementation works by calling your `operator !` on the receiver object, then returning the opposite result.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting, but if I can't use C++11?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your usage it looks like you need to overload the `bool` operator and not the `!` operator.

```
class obj
{
public:

    operator bool() const
    { return this->str.length() == 0; }

private:

    string str;

};
```

**EDIT**

ildjarn provided a nice link in the comments to the dangers of doing a simple `bool` overload.  It's definitely worth the read

[http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Safe_bool)

Comment: `operator bool` is very dangerous, hence the existence of the [safe bool idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool).

Comment: Just a note that an *implicit* operator bool is dangerous, but an explicit one (as @templatetypedef used, but available only in C++11) is much safer.